# How to get only the provider connection string from Web.Config in EF setup?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a project which is using Entity Framework. However, I need to execute some SQL queries (without the use of EF), and would like to retrieve the connection string from the Web.Config. Getting the full connection string is fine using:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseName"].ConnectionString;
```

Which returns the full connection string for the EF like this.

```
metadata=res://*/NameDB.csdl|res://*/NameDB.ssdl|res://*/NameDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=name-db;Initial Catalog=Name;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient
```

I require just the "provider connection string" section from this. Is there any clever way of doing this? Or do I just have to search the string for it using something like regex?

Any help/advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` Object to get the `ProviderConnectionString`

```
string s= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseName"].ConnectionString;
        System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder e = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder(s);
        string ProviderConnectionString = e.ProviderConnectionString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use
var Provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["defautconnection"].ProviderName